# Java drawImage much faster in eclipse compared to when compiled

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, drawimage, compiled

When I run my program from eclipse, it runs fine with very little load on the CPU. JProfiler (watching the program run from eclipse) says most is taken up by collision detection and drawing. When JProfiler is watching the compiled jar run, 97% of it's cpu use comes from drawImage. It's running around twice - three times as fast in eclipse.

Why is this?

This loads once to get the images off of a sprite sheet (All images are buffered images)

```
SpriteMan(Map xMap, Board xBoard)
    {
        mMap = xMap;
        mBoard = xBoard;
        try
        {
            bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("sprites.PNG"));
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.PNG"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                sprites[i][j] = bigImg.getSubimage(i * width,j * height,width,height);

                iSprites[i][j] = config.createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
                //iSprites[i][j] = toImage(sprites[i][j]);

                for(int x = 0; x<32; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y<32; y++)
                    {
                        iSprites[i][j].setRGB(x, y, sprites[i][j].getRGB(x,y));
                    }
                }

                loadedImage+=1;

            }
        }

    }
```

After this, the sprites are saved to their corresponding objects
(also only called once)

```
BlockGround(Map xMap, int X, int Y)
    {
        super(xMap, X, Y);

        mSprite = mMap.mBoard.mSpriteMan.sprites[0][0];
        mCollidable = true;
        mChar = 'G';
    }
```

The blocks are drawn using:

```
g2.drawImage(mSprite,null, x, y);
```

EDIT-----
Thank you so much! The program runs normally now (After updating my JRE) although I seem to have messed something up and it took a lot of fiddling to get eclipse running again, but hey, it works!

Comment: ok, what's the question here?

Comment: How can we know without a representative sample of code?

Comment: *"Java drawImage much faster in eclipse compared to when compiled"*  My first guess is that it uses the `-server` option when invoking the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you upload the jar to a webserver by any chance? If so, the slowdown may be caused by that server.

Comment: No, I'm running directly off a folder on my hard drive (if I'm understanding what you're asking)

Comment: Okay, then the problem is in the java runtime vm. I've encountered some strange things with Java, so it is possible. Try downloading and installing a different revision of Java Runtime. Also, check the compiler settings in eclipse to find out to which version it compiles the code.

Comment: I've also reviewed the code and that seems valid. Here's to hoping things resolve with updating the jre, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that eclipse is using a more stable version of java than your system is set to use by default. Can't really tell without some code.

---Edit---
in command prompt use "java -version" and set your eclipse project to use that. then it should be the same.

Comment: Hm... can you elaborate? (I sent this to one of my friends and it also ran poorly) Also, I just added some code. Do you need code of another part?

Comment: in the project settings, what JRE are you using for eclipse?

Comment: Thanks, I'm updating my JRE right now. It's running JavaSE-1.6 (jre7) in eclipse.